# Scid vs. PC: a hint needed

Tags: engines, scid, winboard

I have now installed  **Scid vs. PC** and I have made my first move with White with **1. e4**. Now the engine computes the position tree. How can I stop it and make it move with Black after some fixed time ?
It has just 6 second per move but it computes indefinitely:

[image: Screenshot of Scid vs. PC]

Comment: Are you sure you started a game and not the analysis engine?

Comment: @Hauptideal No. I have started game by `new game` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: I am slightly confused because the screenshot shows that you have chosen time per move. But you said you tried "New Game". In my scid vs pc, when I want to play a game, I choose Play --> Computer - UCI Engine, which works, while Game --> New Game just opens a game in edit mode.